# Angular adding "unsafe" to url when trying to download an file

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, download, unsafe

I have a small AngularJS app where I am trying to open an uploaded image and am running into the issue where angular adds "unsafe:" at the beginning of the URL. I have added the following line in my app config to sanitize the URL, but it is not working for me:

```
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|blob:chrome-extension):|data:image|\//);
```

I am using Angular v1.3.0 so I am using the correct property name. I am using Chrome mostly, but I have the same issue in other browsers. Also, the beginning of my image looks like this:

```
unsafe:data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...
```

Any idea what am I missing in my regex? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to remove the final `|` or else anything that has a forward slash will be matched.

Comment: If you could just simplify the problem statement, someone would be able to help you. You are using regular expressions for something. You can only do stuff like find/replace, etc.. Any engine understands the simple expression you use.

Comment: @sln: s/he's passing the regex to this angular method: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider)

Answer (score 1):

If you `$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist()` without the regexp parameter it returns the currently defined regexp .

Running this code on an empty angular 1.3.0:

```
app.config(function ($compileProvider) {
    console.log($compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist()); // 
});
```

I got this result - `/^\s*((https?|ftp|file|blob):|data:image\/)/`

And the base64 encoded JPEG using the basic `<img ng-src="{{main.src}}">` actually works as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/dr7sv6df/4/), and [another one](http://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/ccqz50dc/1/) with a png. Also look at the console to see the regexp.

Another test I've run is to move the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` out of the scope binded string and put it the ng-src:

`<img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{main.src}}">`

As you can see it [worked](http://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/ccqz50dc/) as well.

To make a long story short - you don't need to define a regexp in 1.3.0 and above for data:image/*, as it's defined by default.

I can't be sure what's the problem, but maybe you've got another definition of 
imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist somewhere in your code or the data uri is broken somehow.